# Extended Facebook Access Token Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have an app that uses the JavaScript SDK to get one of the Facebook 2-hour "short-lived" tokens.  I then take this token and send it to the endpoint below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This goes fine and I am returned a new token and expiration date that is ~60 days away.  However, Facebook Graph API calls continue to work with the old token (short lived) and fail with the new token (long lived).  Am I misunderstanding something?  I believe the new token should work, and possibly both but certainly not the old token exclusively.

Comment: I agree with you. Both tokens should work. I was doing this just a few days ago, and I did not run into any problems. Maybe you did something wrong? The code you present looks correct.